# RecyclerView change item layout on click

Tags: android, layout, draw

I have this list-view like Activity:

[image]

I want to change the item layout on click like this:

[image]

My RecycleView Adapter:
      public class ComenziViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private final List<Comanda> mValues;
private final ComenziFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener;
public ComenziViewAdapter(List<Comanda> items, ComenziFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener listener) {
    mValues = items;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_comenzi, parent, false);
    View expandedView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_comenzi_expanded,parent,false);

    return new ViewHolder(view,expandedView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
    holder.mIdView.setText(""+mValues.get(position).getId());
    holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).getTraseu());

    holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.setView(holder.getExpandedView());

            listener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mValues.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public View mView;
    public View expandedView;
    public TextView mIdView;
    public TextView mContentView;
    public Comanda mItem;

    public ViewHolder(View view,View expandedView) {
        super(view);
        mView = view;
        this.expandedView = expandedView;
        mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
        mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
    }
    public View getView()
    {
        return this.mView;
    }
    public void setView(View view)
    {
        mView = view;
    }
    public View getExpandedView()
    {
        return this.expandedView;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
    }
}
```

}

How can I change the layout when users click on item ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the correct way of doing it (changing ViewHolder setView)

The simple solution is making "expanded" view as gone in R.layout.fragment_comenzi and making it visible when click registered.

Comment: Good idea, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

1. In the layout file I added a second LinearLayout with INVISIBLE state.
2. The ViewHolder has a boolean property state which represents the list-item state ( false - not expanded ( second LinearLayout hidden ), true - expanded ( second LinearLayout visible )).
3. Changed the ClickListener:

   ```
   holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           LinearLayout expandedLayout = (LinearLayout) holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.comenzi_expanded_layout);

           expandedLayout.setVisibility(!holder.state ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
           holder.state = !holder.state;
           listener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder.mItem);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: I recommend you to store the expanded state of item not in ViewHolder but in Adapter. Like making a map or arrayList (referencing your model Comanda or position, respectively), because viewHolder would be reused when you scroll recyclerview and so the item would be expanded not only  the one you clicked on, but also the one that was reused :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey this may be late but check this out. I solved it using Expandable RecyclerView.

[Expandable RecyclerView](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view)

Also you can check this 4 step guide.

[Big Nerd Ranch 4 step guide](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/expand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps/)